# Why is my eloquent javascript solution crashing?

Tags: javascript, loops, eloquent, infinite

I am trying to solve the last problem from chapter 2 of Eloquent JavaScript. It is at the very bottom of this page: http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html

(I tried copy pasting but the hashtag symbols keep messing up the formatting).

This is my code that crashes. It seems like it's stuck in an infinite loop or something but I can't see why!

```
var grid = "";
var bool = true;
var size = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if(bool = true) {
     for(var i = 0; i < (size/2); i++) {
        grid += " #";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = false;
  }
  else {
     for(var i = 0; i < (size/2); i++) {
        grid += "# ";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = true;
  }
}
console.log(grid);
```

Comment: You're trying to do *comparisons* with `=`, which is the **assignment** operator. You want `==` or `===` in your `if` statement.

Comment: `if(bool = true)`! - that will make sure that bool is always true.

Comment: if (bool) is better... but calling a boolean bool is kind of odd.. also you really need to reorganize the order of operations

Answer (score 1):

You're using the assignment operator = instead of comparator ( == or ===) . I.d probably change the name of the variable inside the second cycle for.. It may mess up with the one from the outer for cycle

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- `if(bool = true)` should be `if(bool == true)` (causing the infinite loop)
- `for(var i = 0; i < (size/2); i++)` should be `for(var j = 0; j < (size/2); j++)`  (`i` is already used in the outer loop)

Suggestions:

- Change `bool` to something like `odd_row`
- If you want to check if a `boolean` variable is `true`, you don't need the comparison: `if(variable)` also works

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/t3rxx9dk/

```
var grid = "";
var bool = true;
var size = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if(bool == true) {
     for(var j = 0; j < (size/2); j++) {
        grid += " #";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = false;
  }
  else {
     for(var j = 0; j < (size/2); j++) {
        grid += "# ";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = true;
  }
}
console.log(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use another name for your iterator, you always use "i", that might cause issues

Answer (score 0):

### basic issues with your code

```
var grid = "";
var bool = true;
var size = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if(bool = true) {
 //       ^ -- trouble
     for(var i = 0; i < (size/2); i++) {
     //      ^  another piece of trouble
        grid += " #";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = false;
  }
  else {
     for(var i = 0; i < (size/2); i++) {
        grid += "# ";
     }
     grid += "\n";
     bool = true;
  }
}
console.log(grid);
```

## on a better way to organize the code

```
var grid = ""
var shiftLine = false;
var size = 8;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   for(var k = 0; k < (size >> 1); k++) {
      grid += shiftLine? " #" : "# ";
   }
   shiftLine = !shiftLine;
   grid += "\n";
}
```

#### outputs

```
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
```

### an exercise

As an exercise for you to review... Here is a way to do this in javascript in a way that takes advantage of Arrays and Strings and demonstrates a few different concepts of functional programming.

```
  var size = 8;
  var grid = 
   Array(size)
   .join(
         Array((size>>1)+1) // START HERE: create empty array of 1+ size/2 
                            // because we want to delimit it '# ' to get
                            // size/2 '#'s
           .join('# ')      // join its elements using "# "
                            //    this gives you a string "# # # # " 
           .trim() + '\n'   // trim off last space and add newline
    )                       // join these lines into an array of size (see Array(size) above)
   .trim()                  // trim off the empty element at the end (due to last new-line)
   .split('\n')             // split it up into array elements because we need to shift every second line
   .map(function(element, index, array) { // for each element (a line of # # # #) 
           if(index % 2 === 0)            // if its index is even
               return " " + element;      //   tack on a leading space
           else                           // otherwise
               return element;            //   leave it alone
    })
    .join('\n');                          // now join everything with a new line

   console.log(grid);
```